# Populate a new array with the same element repeated N times

Tags: php, arrays, repeat

Basically I need to create this array (given x = 3)

```
array('?','?','?');
```

I could do

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
    $arr[] = '?';
```

But it's not so elegant. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [array_fill( start_index, num, value )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php):

```
$arr = array_fill(0, 3, '?');
```

Answer (score 0):

To address the question of *how to push the same element a number of times onto an array*, it's worth noting that while `array_fill()` is certainly the most elegant choice for generating a new array, this is the only thing it can do. It cannot actually push elements onto an existing array.

So while a basic loop isn't particularly exciting, it does work well in situations where you have an existing array you want to add to, regardless of whether it's already empty or not.

```
$arr = ['a', 'a', 'a'];

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $arr[] = 'b';
}
print_r($arr);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => a
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [4] => b
    [5] => b
)
```

To achieve the same thing with `array_fill()` it requires an additional merge:

```
$arr = array_merge($arr, array_fill(0, 3, 'b'));
```

Comment: The asker already knows how to push within a loop.  The advice on appending more elements to an already populated array is moreso topically related to the content found @ [Duplicate each string in a flat array N times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68909837/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most performant (especially if the additions is large), but just as an alternative.

```php
<?php
$foo = ['a'];
array_push($foo, ...array_fill(0, 3, 'b'));
print_r($foo);
```

Would give something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => b
    [3] => b
)
```

Comment: This answer's advice is found at [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76318084/2943403).  Adam may have found that answer by clicking my comment under BadHorsie's answer.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I'll add to this page that `array_pad()` can be used as well (but I prefer the semantics of "filling" an array with `array_fill()`).  I would not choose to call two functions when one function will do, however `str_split(str_repeat())` offers the same effect.

Codes with identical output: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aG8TC))

```
var_export(array_pad([], 3, '?'));
```

---

```
var_export(array_fill(0, 3, '?'));
```

---

```
var_export(str_split(str_repeat('?', 3)));
```