# Duplicate each string in a flat array N times

Tags: php, arrays, repeat

I would like to repeat each value 3 times and put it in the correct order.  In place of each original element 3 copies of itself should take its place.

Given the following one-dimensional array of strings:

```
$chars = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

So result would be:

```
$duplicatedChars = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"];
```

I have tried working with `str_repeat()`, but this does not create separate strings.

This attempt doesn't create enough elements, it only repeats the string within each element.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($chars as $char) {
    $result[] = str_repeat($char, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_repeat` creates a single string, not an array.

Use `array_fill()` to create an array with N copies of a value. Then append the array to the result.

```
foreach ($chars as $char) {
    $result = array_merge($result, array_fill(0, 3, $char));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the number of repeats, you can get the desired output using a `foreach` and `for`

1. Loop through the original array
2. For `$repeat + 1` times; push the char to `$result`

```php
<?php

$chars = ["a", "b" , "c"];
$result = [];
$repeat = 3;

foreach ($chars as $char) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $repeat; $i++) {
        $result[] = $char;
    }
}
    
var_dump($result);
```

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
```

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCsIwDIbPzVOEsMPGPAgeO/FBxpBYKxUUQ@u8yJ69prWXJD//90WC5DydJAhA5wLHhEeciWmHdCHU6Wix0EWf1se7dP8knks6WIDbK3p2Afvmc8J6DfgFo6UWd0X3FnVP2OSSxrEypn2fF8WqasFssIEB@HA8X9en9I0ZbM4/)

---

[@Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68909896/5625547) has the same 'idea', but uses

- `array_merge` instead off `$result[] = ;`
- `array_fill` instead off an extra `for`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get by without the loops as `array_fill` will take an array:

```
$result = array_merge(...array_fill(0, 3, $chars));
```

Or you could use a string:

```
$result = str_split(str_repeat(implode($chars), 3));
```

If needed just `sort` to get the order that you show.

Comment: The implode-repeat-split approach does not order the elements correctly. https://3v4l.org/6cApO

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a few more techniques for completeness.  Solutions that leverage the magic number 3 will be more scalable, but I'll also show some less scalable approaches which repeat a variable or an action 3 times.

- A body-less loop pushing each element into a new array 3 times: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3DQCZ))

  ```
  $result = [];
  foreach (array_chunk($chars, 1) as [0 => $result[], 0 => $result[], 0 => $result[]]);
  var_export($result);
  ```
- A functional loop calling `array_fill()` and `array_merge()` on every iteration: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kbMJD))

  ```
   var_export(
       array_reduce(
           $chars,
           fn($result, $v) => array_merge($result, array_fill(0, 3, $v)),
           []
       )
   );
  ```
- Transpose and flatten 3 copies of the input array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/I8Xrk))

  ```
   var_export(
       array_merge(...array_map(null, $chars, $chars, $chars))
   );
  ```

  or: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lZ25v))

  ```
   var_export(
       array_merge(...array_map(null, ...array_fill(0, 3, $chars)))
   );
  ```
- Looped calls of `array_fill()` with its returned array spread as parameters of `array_push()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/r56vC))

  ```
   $result = [];
   foreach ($chars as $char) {
       array_push($result, ...array_fill(0, 3, $char));
   }
   var_export($result);
  ```
- Looped calls of `array_pad()` with a growing maximum array count: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/D4o4F))

  ```
   $result = [];
   foreach ($chars as $char) {
       $result = array_pad($result, count($result) + 3, $char);
   }
   var_export($result);
  ```
- A `for()` loop calling `array_fill()` and `array_splice()` on every iteration: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GtIi1))

  ```
   for ($i = count($chars) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
       array_splice($chars, $i, 1, array_fill(0, 3, $chars[$i]));
   }
   var_export($chars);
  ```